# MVC For..Each how to set class conditionally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a For...Each loop of a list in an MVC View. What I need to do is look at a property to determine if the records has been marked as deleted and then I would set the Bootstrap class of "danger" on a table row.

I can do a look at the property and write our the table row for each condition but that seems like extra work. If I use the following code Razor doesn't like the fact that it can't see the initial  tag. Any suggestions on how to cleanly accomplish this?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
{
    if (item.IsDeleted == 1)
    {
        @Html.Raw("<tr class='danger'>")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Raw("<tr>")
    }
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simpler way for your problem

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
{
    <tr class="@(item.IsDeleted ? "danger" : string.Empty) ">  
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I could have sworn I tried something like this but it didn't work. I might put the "@" sign in the wrong spot. Either way, I followed this and got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
    {
            <tr class="@(Model.deleted ? "danger" : "")"> 
            <td>@item.FirstName</td>
            <td>@item.LastName</td>
            <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply work with it this way

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
{
 if (item.IsDeleted == 1)
 {
    <tr class="danger">
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
    </tr>
 }
 else
 {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
    </tr>
 }
```

> or an alternative is

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
{
   <tr @(item.IsDeleted != 1 ? String.Empty : "class=\"danger\"" )>

        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion is what I was initially doing but I have several more table cells than what I posted and it just seemed like a lot of repetitive code. Your alternative is closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: Did that work for you ?

Comment: I used @Rahul suggestion which was similar to what you posted.